# Know if code is in NodeWebkit or just in the browser

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, multiplatform

It'd be great if I could have the same javascript run in both the browser and node-webkit without any errors. But I'd also like to add features that are specific to either platform, like a "hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit" in the node-webkit version, but not in the browser version. Is there some sort of conditional I can test to see if I am in node-webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check

```
navigator.userAgent
```

or write your code in a way that you're first checking the features you want to use and fall back to another solution, which is the recommended way in most cases. Because what if some feature gets implemented in an update? You want to go back and change your code every time any browser updates?